# Attempt to assign property of non-object in Controller store method in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, controller, store

Im new in laravel, please help me with this thing

I have store method in controller and try to set property in that method

```
public function store(Request $request) {

    $configuration = $this->validate(request(), [
      'device_name' => 'required',
      'sn' => 'required'
    ]);

    $configuration->timezone = "+4"; 
    configuration::create($configuration);

    return back()->with('success', 'configuration has been added');
}
```

But when I try to submit the request I get this error

> Attempt to assign property of non-object

**What did i do wrong in above method?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is:

```
$configuration->timezone = "+4";
```

line. `$configuration` is PHP array and not object. Change it into:

```
$configuration['timezone'] = '+4';
```

to make it work.